# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found 3

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

In this code, throws me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at com.cristianvalero.filetransfers.main.client.Client.askToDo(Client.java:98)
    at com.cristianvalero.filetransfers.main.client.Client.run(Client.java:64)
    at com.cristianvalero.filetransfers.main.client.Client.main(Client.java:36)
```

Method that throws the error:

```
private String askToDo()
{
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What would you like to do? [help]: ");
    String a = teclado.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    teclado.close();
    return a;
}
```

But in this code that executes before the other code, no throws any error.

```
private void setConnection() //Type of bookmarks "servers":["casa:1.1.1.1:3306", "trabajo:1.1.1.1:7809"]
{
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("New server [N] or Connect previous server [P]: ");
    final String typed = teclado.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    if (typed.equals("n"))
        noHaveServers(teclado);
    else if (typed.equals("p"))
    {
        if (ServerList.getAllServers(CONFG).size() == 0)
            noHaveServers(teclado);
        else
            haveServers(teclado);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, I can't understand you.");
        teclado.close();
        setConnection();
    }

    teclado.close();
}
```

PD: This methods are in the Client class that is extended of Thread and are called from the run() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't close the Scanner `teclado` in `setConnection()`. Closing a Scanner also closes its associated stream. Then in `askToDo`, when you create another Scanner, System.in is already closed.

You should have a single top-level static Scanner object, initialized with System.in, and use that everywhere in your class instead of creating a new Scanner in each method.

Comment: I removed the close scanner but throws the same error.