# Method getting non blank input

Tags: java

I've made method taking non blank input so I can validate input to my list.

```
public String getNonBlankInput(String text){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(text);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    while (input.isEmpty() || input.equals(" ")) {
        System.out.println("Input is empty.");
        System.out.println(text);
        input = scan.nextLine();
    }
    scan.close();

    return input;

}
```

I would like to use this in my method which adds objects to my LinkedList. Here is code of this method:

```
public void addMenu(){
    String log = getNonBlankInput("Enter login: ");
    String pass = getNonBlankInput("Enter password: ");
    String web = getNonBlankInput("Enter website: ");

    Entry newEntry = new Entry(web,log,pass);
    edao.addEntry(newEntry);
}
```

The problem is, whatever I've put as login, password or website I'm getting Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
at com.password.PasswordManager.data.InputValidation.getNonBlankInput(InputValidation.java:12)
at com.password.PasswordManager.input.MenuImplementation.addMenu(MenuImplementation.java:15)
```

Anyone have a clue what is wrong here? Before I've created method getNonBlankInput everything was ok.

Comment: the problem may be that you are creating and closing multiple `Scanner` objects. Essentially, when you close the `System.in` stream, it cannot be opened again. [See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116815/exception-in-thread-main-java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found-3). A suggestion is to pass in a `Scanner` object for `getNonBlankInput()` and close the scanner after `edao.addEntry()`. This should fix your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209110/java-util-nosuchelementexception-no-line-found

Comment: @snr `Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in)` is being called 3 times from 3 `getNonBlankInput()` calls.

Comment: @user3170251 yes, exactly.

Comment: @snr, each call of `getNonBlankInput` will open and close a scanner on `System.in` closing that stream... once close, `System.in` can't be open again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are creating and closing multiple `Scanner` instances. Essentially, when you close the `System.in`, it cannot be opened again. A suggestion is to create a `Scanner` instance in `addMenu()`and pass in that scanner to getNonBlankInput() and close the scanner after `edao.addEntry()`.

```
public void addMenu(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    String log = getNonBlankInput("Enter login: ", scan);
    String pass = getNonBlankInput("Enter password: ", scan);
    String web = getNonBlankInput("Enter website: ", scan);

    Entry newEntry = new Entry(web,log,pass);
    edao.addEntry(newEntry);
    scan.close();
}

public String getNonBlankInput(String text, Scanner scan){
    ...
}
```

Comment: this would just give the same problem when you need to call `addMenu` again... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using three instance of `java.util.Scanner` in `addMenu` method. You have to used only one instance of `java.util.Scanner`. Remove the instance of `java.util.Scanner` and Scanner's `close()`, then add this as class variable.

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Make sure you close input when you done with it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and time. I have used one Scanner and decided not to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and is when create multiple instantiation of `Scanner` target `System.in` then close after first then this error append.

What I suggest you is to use only one `Scanner` or don't close it and this work too.

**Example**

```
public void addMenu() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String log = getNonBlankInput("Enter login: ", scan);
    String pass = getNonBlankInput("Enter password: ", scan);
    String web = getNonBlankInput("Enter website: ", scan);

    scan.close();
    ...
}

public String getNonBlankInput(String text, Scanner scan){

    System.out.println(text);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    do {
        if (input.isEmpty() || input.equals(" ")) {
            System.out.println("Input is empty.");
            System.out.println(text);
            input = scan.nextLine();
        }

    } while ((input.isEmpty() || input.equals(" ")) && scan.hasNextLine());

    return input;

}
```

**Example 2**

```
public void addMenu() {
    String log = getNonBlankInput("Enter login: ");
    String pass = getNonBlankInput("Enter password: ");
    String web = getNonBlankInput("Enter website: ");
    ...
}

public String getNonBlankInput(String text){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(text);
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    while (input.isEmpty() || input.equals(" ")) {
        System.out.println("Input is empty.");
        System.out.println(text);
        input = scan.nextLine();
    }
    //scan.close();
    return input;
}
```